Query across multiple columns
I have a database (called Matches) where there is only one table for the results of a sport (football).
The table (called Matches) has two columns for the teams and two columns for the score.
+-----+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+
| ID  | TIME                | HOME                    | VISIT                   | HOME_RESULT | VISIT_RESULT |
+-----+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+
|   1 | 2024-07-20 21:15:00 | Bayern (Furious)        | PSG (Ozil)              |           4 |            3 |
|   2 | 2024-07-20 21:15:00 | Real Madrid (Dennis)    | Inter (Anthem)          |           2 |            3 |
|   3 | 2024-07-20 21:00:00 | Real Madrid (Dennis)    | PSG (Ozil)              |           3 |            1 |
|   4 | 2024-07-20 21:00:00 | Inter (Anthem)          | Man City (Cruise)       |           3 |            1 |
|   5 | 2024-07-20 20:30:00 | RB Leipzig (Chemist)    | Bayern (Nio)            |           5 |            4 |
|   6 | 2024-07-20 20:30:00 | Bayer 04 (aibothard)    | Dortmund (Panic)        |           2 |            2 |
|   7 | 2024-07-20 20:15:00 | VfB Stuttgart (Cantona) | Dortmund (Panic)        |           1 |            2 |
|   8 | 2024-07-20 20:00:00 | Napoli (Jack)           | Roma (Socrates)         |           3 |            1 |
|   9 | 2024-07-20 20:00:00 | Bayern (Nio)            | Dortmund (Panic)        |           1 |            1 |
|  10 | 2024-07-20 20:00:00 | VfB Stuttgart (Cantona) | RB Leipzig (Chemist)    |           2 |            4 |
|  11 | 2024-07-20 19:45:00 | VfB Stuttgart (Cantona) | Bayer 04 (aibothard)    |           4 |            1 |
|  12 | 2024-07-20 19:45:00 | RB Leipzig (Chemist)    | Dortmund (Panic)        |           3 |            6 |

I need two queries but need to know if it's possible to get values from two columns (HOME and VISIT) simultaneously.
For example in this situation I need to know:
From unique team (HOME and VISIT) how many goals do (HOME_RESULT and VISIT_RESULT)? (i.e Bayern (Nio) have 5. 1 one HOME_RESULT and 4 on VISIT_RESULT)
How many matches do all the unique Teams? In that case how many sort and show unique results? (i.e Bayern (Nio) do 2 matches only)
Thanks in advance

To find total number of goals per team, something like this should work:
SELECT Team, SUM(Result) AS TotalResult, COUNT(*) AS MatchCount
FROM (
  SELECT Home AS Team, Home_Result AS Result
  FROM Matches

  UNION

  SELECT Visit AS Team, Visit_Result AS Result
  FROM Matches
) AS s
GROUP BY Team

I have here assumed that the name of the table is Matches.

I get an error: "ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias"

I added aliases.

I get an error: "near 'AS s2GROUP BY TEAM' at line 9"

Now I found a place where I could test queries without installing MySQL and have fixed the query.
